# Merge tag [vertx.io] into [vert.x]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Since vert.x is the official name of the [project](http://vertx.io/) [vertx.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vertx.io) should be merged into [vert.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vert.x)

Comment: Seems simple enough to retag

Comment: I guess we're talking about the same thing, just my wording is not that differentiated :) Isn't merging A into B the same as retagging all former A posts with B?

Comment: From your phrasing I assumed you thought this would be some automated process.

Comment: This is the first time I'm proposing something like this. I thought the process would work like this, that some user with higher priviliges would initiate a merge/retag and then all As are Bs

Comment: I agree, they indeed are the same thing, plus there's no `vertx.io`, that's the website of the project (at least as of today)